# gnuplot internal column argument clashes with container bash script arguments

Tags: bash, gnuplot, heredoc

I have the following code within a bash script which prepares the input data to plotting.

The code executes fine when run in a gnuplot interpreter but in the bash script it replaces $2 which is meant to represent columns 2 of the ${outdir}/counts.txt data file by the second bash arguments (input file having nothing to do anymore with the plot)

How can i edit this so that $1 and $2 remain private to the gnuplot block?

```
  #!/bin/bash

  .. bash code

  gnuplot <<-EOFMarker
    set datafile separator ","
    set key autotitle columnhead
    set style line 1 \
        linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
        linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
        pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
    set yrange [*:100]
    set xlabel "mappability %"
    set ylabel "% above threshold"
    max(a,b)=a>b?a:b
    a=-99999999.
    set terminal pngcairo
    set output 'mappability_plot.png'
    plot '${outdir}/counts.txt' using 1:(a=max(a,$2),0/0) notitle, \
        '' using 1:(100*$2/a) notitle with linespoints linestyle 1
    EOFMarker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$1` and `$2`, try `column(1)` and `column(2)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the shell from expanding `$something` in a here-document by escaping the `$` character with a backslash:

```
gnuplot <<-EOFMarker
    [...]
    plot '${outdir}/counts.txt' using 1:(a=max(a,\$2),0/0) notitle, \
        '' using 1:(100*\$2/a) notitle with linespoints linestyle 1
    EOFMarker
```

Note that `${outdir}` is not escaped, so the shell will go ahead and replace it normally. BTW, you'll also need to escape any backtick or backslash (escape) characters you want passed through to the program without being interpreted.

BTW, it doesn't apply here, but you can turn off *all* substitutions in the here-document by quoting the delimiter:

```
gnuplot <<-'EOFMarker'
    $things `that` $won't \be $expanded
EOFMarker
```

The reason that won't work here is that it'd keep the shell from expanding `${outdir}` as well, and I presume that's not what you want.

Comment: I tried escaping $2 and it did not do. Using column(2) by contrast did the job.